# Python find timezone by + or - date

Tags: python, date

I found a lot of post about converting a time to a other timestamp.
But I cant find any solutions about my question.

I've got the time like the example below;

```
Mon, 27 Sep 2017 19:28:34 +0100
```

Is there a way how I can tell what timezone belongs to +0100 and return it?
I would like to do this with a lot of records, and make a own list with all timezones doens't seem the best way.

So it should print for example:

```
Europa Amsterdam GMT + 1
```

Comment: Make a list or dictionary of all timezones. Split your date on spaces and take the last element using [-1], then match it with the list or dictionary and print the Timezone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a human-readable timezone name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489183/how-can-i-get-a-human-readable-timezone-name-in-python)