# How can derived from ISO 8061 string datetime to get timezone name in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

Input: **2016-09-20T16:43:45+05:30**

Output: **Asia/Kolkata** //*Expected Result*

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See also "Time Zone != Offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some useful libraries for handling datetimes, such as [python-dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and pytz.

For your case, probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489183/how-can-i-get-a-human-readable-timezone-name-in-python/35086646#35086646) may help you

Comment: Thanks, @vittorio-camisa for sharing stack overflow post. It's helped me.